# In a vue.js app why is the public folder kept outside of the src folder?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am just scaffolding out a new Vue.js project and almost every example out there places the `public` or `assets` folder containing css and image files outside of the `src` folder which has the rest of the application code.

To me it appears that if `src` is meant to contain all the original source code for the application, then surely the `public` folder which contains css and images is also part of that source and should be kept in that folder?

Is there any reason why I have to keep my static files outside of the `src` folder? I am using Webpack to build a `dist` folder anyway and at the moment using the `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy files from `public` into `dist`.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3184

Comment: @Estradiaz im not using vue-cli to create my project. i am doing it all from scratch

Comment: The creator oft vue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3184#issuecomment-458341262 ... But if you do it yourself then I wonder why you compare with vue CLI

Comment: @Estradiaz im not comparing with vue-cli, im just comparing with examples of setting up vue projects. it seems that static files are kept in a separate folder that is outside of the `src` folder. Why not just keep it in the `src` folder?

Answer (score 1):

I was confused exactly the same way.

So **I figured it out!** how to make it that way (use src as my public folder) .
Look below for **contentBase**.

- src/index.html
- src/assets/images/*
- src/assets/icons/*

and **this should be my public** folder in Vue, until deployment where I can use the copy-webpack-plugin to my dist folder

```
module.exports = {
    entry : './src/main.js',
    devServer: {
        port: 4200,
        host: 'localhost',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        inline: true,
        overlay: {
            errors: true,
            warnings: true
        },
        contentBase: "./src" //This is the line you need to add!!! to make it PUBLIC
    },
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject:   true,
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
    ...
```